# Best way to store many html5 SVG element(path, circle, line, e.t.c) in mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, svg, storing-data

I'm making SVG drawing app. The final svg element has some scg elements in it:

For example the square element made by path:

```
<path class="annote arrow svg-element" 
id="1487164985946" style="stroke-width: 4px;" fill="transparent" 
stroke="#29AB22" 
d="M100.39999961853027,167.39999961853027L100.39999961853027,190.39999961853027L122.39999961853027,190.39999961853027L122.39999961853027,167.39999961853027L100.39999961853027,167.39999961853027z"></path>
```

And so on. Also the pencil tool provides user do draw any lines he wants. It creates a massive block of coordinates in 'd' property.

I have ideas:

1. Keep all the < svg> content in one db row.
2. Save every element as one row, but it's gonna produce mass db spam.

Could anyone suggest a better sollution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an array object for the same type of element example like

```
[{"path":{"id":"1487164985946","path":"M100.39999961853027,167.39999961853027L100.39999961853027..."},{"id":"1487164985947","path":"M100.39999961853027,167.39999961853027L100.39999961853027..."}}]

[{"line":{"id":"1487164985948","line":"x1,y1,x2,y2"},{"id":"1487164985949","line":"x1,y1,x2,y2"}}]

[{"circle":{"id":"1487164985950","r":"10","cxcy":"20,10"},{"id":"1487164985951","r":"20","cxcy":"20,10"}}]
```

Now after creating this individual array object you have to save this object as it is in column path ,line ,circle of database.